# Phonegap libgif javascript: work in emulator, not device

Tags: javascript, cordova, emulation, device

I'm using libgif.js found at github/buzzfeed/libgif-js to parse gifs in my phonegap app. After building the apk, I used the Genymotion emulator to test the functionality of my app and it works perfectly. I then installed the same apk onto my android tablet and got:

[image]

(**left is fixed, right is broken**).

It does not seem like the functions from libgif.js executed.

I was wondering if libgif.js is not compatible with android devices or if there is something I can implement in my own code or modify libgif.js. My code can be found at https://github.com/kerblaster/framelee. The relevant files are scripts.js, libgif.js, fox/movements/down_dodge.html, and marth/movements/down_dodge.html.